# Почему context может требоваться по разному?

Tags: java, android

Есть стандартный класс `Dialog`

```
new Dialog(...);
```

который как аргумент получает `context` , так вот когда я передаю вот так

```
new Dialog(getAplicationContext());
```

то не работает, а когда вот так

```
new Dialog(MainActivity.this);
```

то работает...

Почему так получается?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/4128589/3212712

Comment: @ЮрийСПб Если я правильно понял, то диалог принимает только `Activity context` в этом причина... Для того, чтоб ограничить продолжительность его жизни... Если активити в котором он был вызван закрывается то диалог автоматически разрушается вместе с ним... Вроде так

Comment: Да, вроде всё верно)